# Does mobiles Phone have any compiler?

Tags: ide, mobile-phones

I've tried to search on the internet that does mobiles have any compilers? if yes then how a code can be compiled without any IDE. But didn't find any information that is specific to my query.

Answer (score 1):

**No,** mobiles or Android phones doesn't have any compiler in them. The applications of Android phones are compiled in **Android Studio**(say) and **.apk file** is installed or extracted in android phone.

If we need any compiler for Turbo C or C++ console based programs then we can download them manually from play store.